# MySQL- Why is LAST_INSERT_ID() not working for me?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
  public function createNewGuide($userID,$guideName)
  {
    $sql =" INSERT INTO myTable(name, updated) 
            VALUES ('$guideName', 'NOW()')";

    //Process query
    $this->query($sql); // This inserts the new row
    $this->query('LAST_INSERT_ID()'); // This throws an error

    return $this->query_result;
  }
```

My query function looks like this:

```
  private function query($sql) 
  {
      $this->query_result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn)
        or die("Unable to query local database <b>". mysql_error()."</b><br>$sql");   
  }
```

I get the following error:

> **MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'LAST_INSERT_ID()'**

I've googled and looked at similar problems, but not found an answer :(

I have not tried the [PHP function mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), as I really would like to do this using SQL.

Comment: You should consider using query parameters instead of inserting values directly into the SQL string. Your code may have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I know - using MySQLi right? I've tried, but I'm not able to prcess queries then. I only get errors :( So I'm handling it as good as I can in other ways.

Comment: You also have an XSS vulnerability in the way you are displaying your database error messages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: This bug? https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23315

Comment: I did some testing and there is definitely a bug here still.  `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns 0.  If you then do `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(column)` you get the right value.  Then if you do it again without the ID, you get the right value.  Insert another row, now try without the ID, it hasn't updated.  SELECT with the id, now it works and it updates something so that without the ID works again, until you insert a new row.  It's broken.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not just use PHP's [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)?

Irrespective...

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

...should work **as long as you've an auto-increment column in the table**.

Comment: Because I think it's safer to get the correct ID using the SQL statement? E.g. when multiple users inserts and updates data in the same table.

Comment: Unless you're using InnoDB and carrying out the above within a transaction, I don't think this will prove to be the case. That said, I believe that the mysql_insert_id is connection specific, hence what you're referring to won't be an issue unless you're sharing the same database connection.

Comment: A am using InnobDB. My problem now with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, is that is just returns 0. Have no idea why.

Comment: Just checking the basics, but does your table actually have an auto-increment column?

Comment: ok, I ended up using mysql_insert_id() - since I can't figure out why `LAST_INSERT_ID()` only returns 0.

Comment: Basically, we need an auto-increment column.  I been trying to get id from the composite key.

Comment: it's better to use in the procedure.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot SELECT:

```
"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. But it returns 0 :( Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

If **SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();** returns 0;

Use this query :

**SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(Id) from table_name order by LAST_INSERT_ID(Id) desc limit 1;**

it will give you the required result.

Answer (score 3):

That won't work without a SELECT:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

or just use `mysql_insert_id`, it's a php function which does the same on the php level. However, use the first method if your table ids are BIGINT.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple Database links into the same enviroment, you should always specify the Link Identifier.

In case of `mysql_insert_id` php function you should always call it using `mysql_insert_id( $link_id );`

In case you call it by SQL query using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID( link_id )`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the `mysql_*` functions, why not just use the [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function, instead of calling `LAST_INSERT_ID()` yourself ?

Still, the SQL error you are getting is probably because the SQL query you are sending to the server is this one :

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Instead of this one :

```
select LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

There should be a `select`, if you are doing an SQL query to... select... some data.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I'm not using the PHP function, because I'm not sure if it will return the correct ID if multiple users at the same time ads or updates data in the same table. However, using `select LAST_INSERT_ID()` only returns 0....

Comment: I'm pretty sure `mysql_last_id` will do exactly what you want, as it's working on the current connection. And it's what I've always used, actually ^^

Answer (score 1):

The guys have already answered that you were missing the SELECT prefix.

By the way, you should watch your INSERT statement... it has a clear door for SQL injection if `$guideName` is not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns zero if no row was inserted.

You should check that your `INSERT` actually succeeded.  Always test the return value of `mysql_query()` and other functions, which is usually `FALSE` if an error occurred.

```
$sql =" INSERT INTO myTable(name, updated) 
        VALUES ('$guideName', 'NOW()')";

if ($this->query($sql) === FALSE) {
  die(mysql_error());
}

if (($result = $this->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")) === FALSE) {
  die(mysql_error()); 
}

if (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) === FALSE) {
  die(mysql_error()); 
}

$id = $row[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I had forgotten to use the SELECT statement. Will test this next time I do some refactoring :)

Comment: Probably the INSERT failed because you put NOW() inside quotes, making it a string literal that is not a valid datetime literal.  You want it to be a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If I were you.  I would get your insert/select last_insert_id to work from the command line or query browser first, before php.  At minimum, this will at least confirm or deny correct sql syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with whoever says you should use `mysql_insert_id`, but if you want to use `LAST_INSERT_ID`, you can use this:

```
function getLastInsertId($db_connection)
{
   $result = 0;

   if($query_result = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();", $db_connection))
   {
      $temp = mysql_fetch_row($query_result);
      $result = $temp[0];   
   }

   return $result;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your table has `datetime`/`timestamp` column and see your query has `NOW()` `varchar` value instead of `datetime` value, so your `SQL query` should have return `false`.

If the query return `false` you will not get last inserted id (always for current connection).

Answer (score 0):

I use

$Last_ID=$mysqli->insert_id;

Once i have problem. Insert_id was int(0) after running insert query.
The matter was in additional "Select" query after "Insert" query before getting insert_id, which throw it, as i assume.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon a solution that might help you with

If you are trying to get the ID of your newly inserted row, then check the result of insertion query,

```
   OkPacket {
          fieldCount: 0,
          affectedRows: 1,
   > > >  insertId: 14,
          serverStatus: 2,
          warningCount: 0,
          message: '',
          protocol41: true,
          changedRows: 0
         }
```